# How can I add additional bindable visual state groups to a button?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, visualstatemanager

I need to extend a button control to add some additional, bindable, visual states.

What I would like to create is an additional boolean property, to bind to, that will create a simple visual state change on the button.  For this example, it could just be an additional border which changes colour according to the boolean value.

All the existing button behaviour should be entirely seperate from this new set of states.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This can certainly be done. [Here's a post](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Create-a-Custom-Control-Inheriting-from-TextBox.aspx) that walks you through the steps you'll need to take, and includes additional information for extending the control with properties (besides just those to hold state) that show up in the final control. The pieces you'll need are:

1. A class that derives from Button (your custom control class)
2. A default style for this control (which goes in /themes/generic.xaml). You can start off with Button's generic style and add your states to it.
3. A dependency property that holds your boolean value
4. A new VisualStateGroup that holds your two new states
5. Some code in your class that glues together changing states with the boolean value you've defined, presumably resulting from user interaction, etc.
6. You may find it's easier to edit the visual state in Blend, depending on how sophisticated your transitions will be, etc.